# Rspec test fails authenthicate_client not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading a legacy project to rails 5 and among the rspec tests that are failing I have one that says:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_redirect
   expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00007fbe5fde51f0 @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::...ch::Http::Headers:0x00007fbe5fdde9e0 @req=#<ActionController::TestRequest:0x00007fbe5fde5358 ...>>>>.redirect?` to return true, got false
 # ./spec/controllers/search_controller_spec.rb:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I am using devise gem to authenticate clients.
The tests are as follows:

```
describe SearchController do

  before(:each) do
    @client = FactoryGirl.create(:client)
  end

  describe "authenticated search" do
    # a bunch of tests
  end

  describe "unauthenticated search" do
    it "requires a user to be authenticated" do
      get :search, params: { q: "tec" }, format: :json

      expect(response).to be_redirect  # FAILING HERE
    end
  end
end
```

If I run the test manually and go to `/search?q=tec` I get redirected to the sign_in page. The `search_controller.rb` has a `before_action :authenticate_client!`

I tried adding `sign_out @client` before the search but it didn't work.
Also tried `current_client.reload` but didn't recognize current_client.

In the authenticated search tests there is a call to `stub_authenticate_client` that has the following code:

```
  def stub_authenticate_client(client)
    allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!) { client }
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_client) { client }
  end
```

in case that is useful to solve this issue.

I also tried creating a `stub_logout_client` method like this:

```
  def stub_logout_client(client)
    allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!) { nil }
    allow(controller).to receive(:current_client) { nil }
  end
```

and calling it at the beginning of the test, but it is still passing the `before_action authenticate_client!`

Also tried what it was suggested [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request)), but didn't work

The search controller that is being tested:

```
class SearchController < ClientApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_client!

  def search
    limit = params[:limit] ? params[:limit].to_i : 10
    query = params[:q].to_s.downcase.strip

    results = {}

    if params[:report]
      results[:this_report] = Report.where("SOME QUERY")
    end

    render json: results
  end
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to include the controller that is under test in the question.

Comment: try this one: `get :search, params: { q: "tec" }, format: :json, headers: {}, env: {}` idea is to reset headers, since headers keep session tokens, cookies and etc. Or do this above the line with `get` :   `cookies.delete(:remember_token)`  token You've to check name of cookie in browser.

Comment: @max included the search controller to the question

Comment: @num8er tried both. For the first one I get `unknown keywords: headers, env` and  and the second one also threw me an error, I changed it to `cookies.delete(:remember_token)` no error, but test keeps failing

Comment: @marimaf are You sure that auth checker works? Like if You open incognito browser and do search without auth. Also try to make set wrong password and check if Your test passing

Comment: @num8er yes, I checked that before and it works, I get redirected to the sign in page

Comment: Have you tried using the Warden test helpers instead of your mocking hack? https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the `be_redirect` check. Changed the test to check for content in the response and that solved it, like this:

```
describe "unauthenticated search" do
    it "requires a user to be authenticated" do
      get :search, params: { q: "tec" }, format: :json
      expect(response.body).to have_content("content from the page I render")
    end
  end
```