# rspec not destroying record and failing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in the process of upgrading a legacy project to rails 5.0 and some tests are failing. I have the following test:

```
describe ItemRun do
  describe "#item_template" do
    context "with an item template that has been deleted" do
      let(:item_template) { ItemTemplate.create! title: "Hello" }
      let!(:item_run) { item_template.item_runs.create! title: "Testing" }

      before do
        item_template.update_attributes(deleted: true)
      end

      it "responds to :title" do
        expect(item_run.item_template.title).to eq ""
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The error reports the following:

```
ItemRun#item_template with a item template that has been deleted responds to :title
     Failure/Error: expect(item_run.item_template.title).to eq ""

       expected: ""
            got: "Hello"

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/models/item_run_spec.rb:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I also tried `item_template.destroy` but got the same result.

`item_template.rb` has the following class defined:

```
  class NullObject
    def title
      ""
    end
  end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post relevant code of `ItemTemplate`, from provided excerpt it is not clear why `title` should change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`destroy` on an active record object will remove it from the database but the object remains in memory.

better would be to do a

```
item_run.reload
```

before the expect, but depending on how you defined the relationship you may then get an error that `item_template` is not found.

If your 'item_template' has

```
has_many :item_runs, dependent: :nullify
```

Then there won't be an error (assuming `item_run` has `belongs_to :item_template, optional: true`)

But as `item_run` will have no `item_template` then doing `item_run.item_template.title` will give you an error of no method on Nil:NilClass.

The underlying quetion is... should an `item_run` exist without an `item_template` ?

If not then do

```
has_many :item_runs, dependent: :destroy
```

And that will destroy the `item_run` automatically.

Comment: item_template has has_many :item_runs, dependent: :destroy  and reload item_run throws me a undefined method `reload' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups... any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I meant item_run.reload ... See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! that did it. Any chance you can have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656005/rspec-test-fails-authenthicate-client-not-working  it might be a similar problem